# How to delete a LaTeX macro while preserving its text content?

Tags: latex, auctex

In TeXStudio by hitting <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> in a LaTeX macro like this `\macroname{content}` while the cursor stands just before the first `{` will result in deleting all that except its `content` (as shown below).

[image]
Put the cursor (point) just before the first curly bracket:

[image]

Hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> and you get:

[image]

How to achieve this in Emacs?

**Update**
According to T.Verron's clarification there is a problem with `C-c C-f C-d` as it complains from error of unbalanced parenthesis when executed within some macros in LaTeX. Consider the below example:
[image]

throws this error: 
 `up-list: Scan error: "Unbalanced parentheses", 8074, 1`. \textenglish{} belongs to polyglossia package.

How to get rid of this caveat?

Comment: Hem, the caveat with the current answer is not about whether auctex fontifies the macro or not, it is about whether the macro is a latex font specification (probably as defined by `TeX-font-list`) or not. For example, try with `\section` or `\footnote`, AUCTeX knows about these macros and fontifies them, but `C-c C-f C-d` will complain about unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: Even if I can update this `TeX-font-list` to include my newly introduced macros, this remains a suboptimal workaround. Otherwise, I don't know what prvents having an eLISP function to deal with it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this function:

```lisp
(defun mg-TeX-delete-current-macro (&optional arg)
  "Remove the current macro.
With an optional argument ARG, delete just the ARG-th macro
starting from the innermost."
  (interactive "*p")
  (let (macro end)
    (when 
    (dotimes (i arg macro)
      (goto-char (TeX-find-macro-start))
      (setq macro (TeX-current-macro)
        end (TeX-find-macro-end))
      ;; If we need to look for an outer macro we have to "exit" from the
      ;; current one.
      (backward-char))
      ;; Return to the beginning of the macro to be deleted.
      (forward-char)
      (re-search-forward
       (concat (regexp-quote TeX-esc) macro "\\(?:\\[[^]]*\\]\\)?"
           TeX-grop "\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)")
       end t)
      (replace-match "\\1")
      ;; Delete the closing brace.
      (delete-backward-char 1))))
```

Limitation: doesn't work with verbatim-like macros.  This function will throw an error (`Wrong type argument: integer-or-marker-p, nil`) if the universal argument is greater than the number of macros enclosing point.

Bind the function to your favorite shortcut.  For example

```lisp
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(local-set-key (kbd "M-DEL") 'mg-TeX-delete-current-macro))
```

to bind it it <kbd>M-DEL</kbd>.

If your buffer has (`!` is point)

```latex
\onemacro{\anothermacro{!argument}}
```

then <kbd>C-2 M-DEL</kbd> will give you

```latex
\anothermacro{argument}
```

Comment: If the point inside innermost group `(gr1(gr2(gr3(gr4))))` do you mean by a prefix `C-u` then 2 it will give me: `(gr1(gr2))`? if it is so, that must be brilliant. I hope you had the time to do it.

Comment: I bound it to `M-DEL` like in TexStudio. Thanks.

Comment: @doctorate  Well, no, my idea is to delete just the second macro, `gr3` in your case.  See the updated answer.  You can implement what you suggested by wrapping a `dotimes` around `when` of the original version of the answer.

Comment: Great function! Now it behaves like a smart *macro-pacman*! one caveat though; when the argument is big and it throws an error the point *jumps* somewhere backward. Can you make it complain while standing in its current place?

Comment: @giordano Any chance this will make it into AucTex? It's very useful!

Comment: @Tyler Thank you!  I have no plan to include this function in AUCTeX, but you can propose it to the mailing list auctex@gnu.org ;-)

Answer (score 9):

From the [AUCTeX manual node on Changing the
font](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/auctex_19.html):

> `C-c C-f C-d`

```
Delete the innermost font specification containing point.
```

Comment: that was a very handy piece in the documentation that I missed. Thanks.

Comment: But it only works for font specifications (and the verification makes sense, for example for `\emph{\randommacro{test}}` it will delete the `\emph`).

Comment: @T.Verron: good clarification.  I'm not aware of a built-in way to do this for arbitrary LaTeX macros.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple function to remove the containing macro at point:

```
(defun TeX-remove-macro ()
  "Remove current macro and return `t'.  If no macro at point,
return `nil'."
  (interactive)
  (when (TeX-current-macro)
    (let ((bounds (TeX-find-macro-boundaries))
          (brace  (save-excursion
                    (goto-char (1- (TeX-find-macro-end)))
                    (TeX-find-opening-brace))))
      (delete-region (1- (cdr bounds)) (cdr bounds))
      (delete-region (car bounds) (1+ brace)))
    t))
```

Hence, with `*` as point:

```
\footnote{Here's a * footnote} 
  => Here's a footnote
```

Given the above function, it's a one-liner to remove all the macros at point:

```
(defun TeX-remove-all-macros ()
  "Remove all containing macros for text at point."
  (interactive)
  (while (TeX-remove-macro)))
```

Hence, again with `*` as point:

```
\footnote{Here's a \textbf{footnote with \emph{emphasized * text}}} 
  => Here's a footnote with emphasized text
```